# Moq: how to assert that methods on my mock object are NOT run?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I have mocks working where I test that methods on my mocked object are called with the correct parameters, and return the right result.

Now I want to check another condition. In this case, NO methods should be run on the mocked object. How can I express this in a unit test?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could create your mock as strict. That way only the methods you Setup (or Expect, depending on which version of Moq you're playing with) are allowed to be run.

```
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
foo.Expect(f => f.Bar());
```

Any time a method is called on foo other than Bar(), an exception will be raised and your test will fail.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure what to look for in the documentation (as little as there is).

Answer (score 3):

The two most straightforward way would be to use MockBehaviour.Strict:

```
var moqFoo = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehaviour.Strict);  
//any calls to methods that there aren't expectations set for will cause exceptions
```

or you could always use a callback and throw an exception from there (if there is a specific method that should not be called.

```
var moqFoo = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehaviour.Loose);  
moqFoo.Expect(f => f.Bar()).Callback(throw new ThisShouldNotBeCalledException());
```

Comment: Your two comments are identical. Is it your intention?

Comment: @Nam Gi VU, no, have removed second occurrence. Thanks for that.